# Variable not overriding C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set a "score" variable, which will change all the time I add up some points every time I call to. My code, however, adds up some points, but if I call it again it sets the value back and adds up. That means that I want to add up one point to 0, it prints 1, and if I want add it again, it will print 1 point again. Here is my code:

```
    class StatusManage
    {
        public int score;

        public void increase()
        {
            score++;
        }
    }

    class QuestionManage
    {
        StatusManage status = new StatusManage();
        public int limit = 4;

        public void choose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your score: {0}", status.score);
            Questions q = new Questions();
            if (status.score >= limit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The end! Congratulation");
                status.score = 0;
            }
            switch (status.score)
            {
                case 0:
                    q.question1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    q.question2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    q.question3();
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void getAnswer(char correctAnswer)
        {
            Console.Write("Type your answer: ");
            ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (char.ToUpper(answer.KeyChar) == correctAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are correct!");
                status.increase();
                choose();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect answer, try it again...");
                getAnswer(correctAnswer);
            }
        }

    }
class Questions
    {
        QuestionManage questionManage = new QuestionManage();

        public void question1()
        {
            // Questions
            // Q1
            text = "How do we declare whole number variables in C#";
            string question = text + "?";
            Console.WriteLine(question);

            letter = 1;
            text = "int 1x = 10";
            string choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 2;
            text = "int x = 10";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 3;
            text = "float x = 10f";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 4;
            text = "string x = \"10\"";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);
            Console.WriteLine();

            questionManage.getAnswer('B');
        }

        public void question2()
        {
            // Questions
            // Q2
            text = "In what country is Stockholm";
            string question = text + "?";
            Console.WriteLine(question);

            letter = 1;
            text = "Germany";
            string choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 2;
            text = "Denmark";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 3;
            text = "Austria";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 4;
            text = "Sweden";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);
            Console.WriteLine();

            questionManage.getAnswer('D');
        }

        public void question3()
        {
            // Questions
            // Q2
            text = "Check";
            string question = text + "?";
            Console.WriteLine(question);

            letter = 1;
            text = "Correct";
            string choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 2;
            text = "Incorrect";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 3;
            text = "Incorrect";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);

            letter = 4;
            text = "Incorrect";
            choice = $"{choicePrefix[letter - 1]}) {text}";
            Console.WriteLine(choice);
            Console.WriteLine();

            questionManage.getAnswer('A');
        }

        public static string text;
        public static int letter;
        public static char[] choicePrefix = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' };
    }
```

And here the result in the console:
[image: Console result]

Thanks for any help

Comment: have you tried initializing score to 0?

Comment: The QuestionManage class's choose() method creates a new instance of the Questions class. But the Questions class then creates a new instance of the QuestionManage class, which then creates a new instance of the StatusManage class, which resets the score to 0.

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: Be aware that although it is resetting the score variable to 0 each time you make a new Questions instance, this is from the help of the debug build. Release build does not guarantee your variable will be init'd to 0. Make sure you init it.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson thank you for your comment! It helped me a lot. I didn't, when creating a new instance it will repeat the other instances again. I tried to replace it with inheritance, but that didn't work also. After that, I tried to give it into just one class (the Questions in the QuestionManage clas) which worked for me. Well, now I have more experiences.

Comment: @AlexCoronas Yes, I have and it didn't work, as said, the problem was it resets the score every time I create a new instance.